# ElasticSearch Client Node Loses Connection on AWS EC2 with Kernel Log "Setting Capacity to 83886080"

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel

I have an ElasticSearch 2.4.4 cluster with 3 client nodes, 3 master nodes, and 4 data nodes, all on AWS EC2. Servers are running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-104-generic x86_64). An AWS Application ELB is in front of the client nodes.

At random times, one of the clients will suddenly write this message to the kernel log:

```
Jan 17 05:54:51 localhost kernel: [2101268.191447] Setting capacity to 83886080
```

Note, this is the size of the primary boot drive in sectors (it's 40GB). After this message is received, the client node loses its connection to the other nodes in the cluster, and reports:

```
[2018-01-17 05:56:21,483][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [prod_es_233_client_1] master_left [{prod_es_233_master_2}{0Sat6dx9QxegO2rM03_o9A}{172.31.101.13}{172.31.101.13:9300}{data=false, master=true}], 
reason [failed to ping, tried [3] times, each with  maximum [30s] timeout]
```

The kernel message seems to be coming from xen-blkfront.c
https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/linux/blob/8277d2088f33ed6bffaafbc684a6616d6af0250b/drivers/block/xen-blkfront.c#L2383

This problem seems unrelated to the number or type of requests to ES at the time, or any other load-related parameter. It just occurs randomly.

The Load Balancer will record 504s and 460s when attempting to contact the bad client. Other client nodes are not affected and return with normal speed.

Is this a problem with EC2's implementation of Xen?